# .Net implementation of standard java classes

Tags: c#, java, .net, portability

Does anyone know of a .Net assembly that contains classes with the same functionality of the typical java types:

For instance, .Net implementations (preferably c#) of the following that contain the same methods that the java classes contain.

java.util.HashMap

java.util.LinkedList

etc...

I know of some fundamental differences between java collections and .net collections, such as the ability to remove elements during enumeration, but that does not mean that most functions cannot be implemented in .net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for the exact same API's or just equivalent classes in the .Net Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for API compatible interfaces with Java, you may want to look into [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/).

Comment: Thanks, Nate.  I just downloaded it.  Why isn't it exactly the same, though?

Comment: This is an implementation of the JVM to run Java code under .Net...As opposed to C# classes that have the same API's as their Java counter parts.

Comment: @Nate:  Do I need to be running the JVM implementation? or can I just use the classes (eg, java.util.ArrayList)  that I need from my c# project?  do you know?

Comment: @Eugenio, I'm sorry, I simply don't know.  I'm only aware of IKVM through reading about and using Mono.  I haven't needed to port or use Java code in .Net or Mono so I haven't looked at it closely.

Comment: @Nate: So you mean that even if I work with an instance of say java.util.ArrayList, there will be a virtual machine running in the background?

Comment: I added a reference to IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll, and I easily created a java.util.ArrayList object and used it without any problem.  It is even compatible with the c# foreach statement. This will be very helpful in porting code.  Thanks, @Nate.

Answer (score 1):

[`System.Collections.Generic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) and [`System.Collections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.aspx) hold the types you are looking for, [`LinkedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) and [`HashTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) respecitively although there are probably better alternatives with generics such as a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) depending on your intentions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Do these classes support .remove() (even inside a foreach loop), .movenext(), etc in the exact same way as in Java code?

Comment: @Eugenio De Hoyos This can be implementation specific especially when trying to modify the collections while enumerating but if you look at the MSDN information linked for the specific implementations you can certainly find a suitable collection.

Comment: @ Quintin:  Thanks again.  I want to preserve the same java syntax and naming conventions, to avoid rewriting code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [System.Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.aspx) or [System.Collections.Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) namespaces in .NET, these contain the main collection classes.

Another useful tool you might want to check out is [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/).  This framework allows you to use the Java API classes from .NET, and provides some mechanisms for interoperate between Java and .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for *exactly* the same methods?

I mean, `HashMap` is *basically* the same as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, while `LinkedList` is *basically* the same as `LinkedList<T>`. So there's that.

I don't know that anyone's made exact clones just because it's unclear what the value of that would be.

Comment: Yes, I want clones, at least on the surface: exact names, and equivalent functionality.  The value is to simplify java to .net migration with little code rewriting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It seems that IKVM does have exact clones (to some extent) of many java classes.

Comment: @Eugenio: While I'm glad you found something useful, I have to admit I'm a little confused about what your actual goal is. You say you're porting Java code to C#, but it sounds like you just want C# code that basically happens to be almost identical to the original Java code. Why are you changing over? Not that I really need to know; I'm just curious.

Comment: There is an open source project in Java that I'd like to edit in C#.  I translated many lines (~6000) by hand over the last days, but I don't want to debug all of these lines for mistakes I made.   Instead, I wrote a simple script to make these files C#-ready:  add namespace stuff, replace incompatible parts of code, etc...  But one thing that was giving me a hard time was dealing with the native java classes.  At first I tried to replace those lines of code.  Then I tried making my own implementations.  Now i can simply use IKVM's classes and reduce the amount of work that I need to do.

Comment: I looked for automated tools, but I am not sure if there is something good out there.  I used Microsofts Java Language Conversion Tool (2005), but the way it handled collections was ridiculous.  It simply replaced java functions with c# functions that seemed similar...  It required lots of post programmer work.